# Name of segue identifier used to arrive at present View Controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the name of the segue identifier used to arrive at the current viewcontroller. For example say I have viewcontroller's A, B and C. Both A and B have a button that segues to C. When the C viewcontoller loads how can I know which view controller I previously segued from?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `sourceSegueId` property of type `NSString*` to your view controller, and set it in each `prepareForSegue` method of source view controllers:

In your destination controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *sourceSegueId;
```

In each `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue.destinationViewController setSourceSegueId:segue.identifier];
}
```

With this code in place you can examine the `sourceSegueId` property inside the destination view controller to learn from which segue the controller has opened.